# Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) - Open Help on page load

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I'm wondering, as opposed to opening the help dialog when the help link is clicked:

```
var help = domConstruct.place(this.html, this.domTarget);
on(help, 'click', lang.hitch(this.parentWidget, 'show'));
```

How might I go about loading the help dialog when the viewer first loads?  So, by default the help opens and needs to be actively closed to interact with the viewer?

It looks like I could use `this.parentWidget.show();` in postCreate but it doesn't block the ability to interact with the underlying viewer.

How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help widget can be opened at start up by adding `openAtStartup: true' to the options like this:

```
help: {
    include: true,
    id: 'help',
    type: 'floating',
    path: 'gis/dijit/Help',
    title: 'Help',
    options: {
        openOnStartup: true
    }
}
```

Note that there is an issue in the current version of CMV with the content being displayed properly when it is opened in this fashion. See [this issue](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/issues/244) for more information.

Comment: Thank you.  I think you intended `openOnStartup` as opposed to `openAtStartup` in the first line?  I noticed `openOnStartup: true` requires `onShow` whereas `openOnStartup: false` requires `onOpen.`  Have you observed that?

Comment: Yes I did mean `openOnStartup`.  I have not observed what you mention. The `onShow` method should work in both situations.

Comment: openOnStartup:false & onOpen works as expected, openOnStartup:true & onShow works as expected, openOnStartup: true & onOpen yields the issue as described in your link (no initial info in navigation tab) and openOnStartup:false & onShow yields only the ContentPane and the word "Help," no TabContainer.

Comment: I've tried openOnStartup:true & onShow and it's doing what I want but I was wondering, I'm using the help widget as a sample for a sort of disclaimer widget.  Everything is working fine on load except for the blocking of ui.  Why wouldn't that be happening?

Comment: perhaps you gave your widget an id other than 'help'? If so, then you'll need to add or change this entry in main.css:      #help_parent_underlay {
    display: block;
}

Comment: Perfect.  Yes, the id was different.  I modified main.css accordingly.  Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: Is hide/show the cancel button (the 'x') configurable?

Comment: Clicking the X icon hides the dialog. Pressing the escape key hides it too.

Comment: I was was wondering more along the lines of hiding the X icon and disabling the escape key behavior.

Comment: This has moved off-topic from the original question. You can post another question though what you are now asking is a question related to dojo and perhaps doesn't belong on gis.stackexchange.com. You can also ask this questions in the #cmv channel on IRC. Similar Q&A is taking place there currently.